# Can I retrieve deleted photos (beyond 1,000) from Photo Stream?

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

Is there any way to access photos from my Photo Stream that were there yesterday before I stupidly downloaded my SD card with over 1,000 photos on it.  Are those earlier photos gone forever or stored somewhere in the Cloud?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have iCloud setup on your computer with auto-import setup? If Photostream was the only place those photos were stored I think you are completely stuck.

Comment: Hi thanks for help ..... yes I do have all that set up at home however I was touring round France for two weeks and my iPhone camera roll storage was getting full so because they were duplicated in Photo Stream I deleted them from camera roll.  They were probably still in Photo Stream last night when I got home but that's when I stupidly stuck my SD card in the Mac and all my 1,500 pics from my SLR camera went into Photo Stream and the earlier ones I'd taken on my iPhone disappeared!  Thanks for trying to help me with this but it sounds like I've definitely lost them. :-(

Comment: Yes, I agree that the situation sounds bleak right now. iPhoto can be setup to automatically import photos and it is possible iCloud can be setup to do that on a PC but I'm not sure. I think iPhoto must be open for it to import though.

Answer (score 1):

The photos are deleted once they go beyond 1000. Unless the photos exist elsewhere, they are gone.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me with this - but yes I think I'm now having to come to terms with the fact that those photos taken on my iPhone at the start of my trip are gone for good - sadly they were taken on the first lovely evening of my trip to France (Reims Cathedral, hotel roof top restaurant and views to die for) and all I can think is why oh why did I leave my SLR camera in the hotel that night!   Aaarrggh!!!!  Anyway, once again thank you - definitely a lesson learned!